# System.ArgumentNullException: Value cannot be null. (Parameter 'key'). What do I wrong?

Tags: c#, entity-framework, asp.net-core, .net-core, entity-framework-core

I got the following error when I try to add a new entity. Does somebody know, what I am doing wrong?

```
System.ArgumentNullException: Value cannot be null. (Parameter 'key')
   at System.Collections.Generic.Dictionary`2.FindValue(TKey key)
   at Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.ChangeTracking.Internal.EntityReferenceMap.TryGet(Object entity, IEntityType entityType, InternalEntityEntry& entry, Boolean throwOnNonUniqueness)
   at Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.ChangeTracking.Internal.StateManager.TryGetEntry(Object entity, IEntityType entityType, Boolean throwOnTypeMismatch)
   at Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.ChangeTracking.Internal.NavigationFixer.InitialFixup(InternalEntityEntry entry, Boolean fromQuery)
   at Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.ChangeTracking.Internal.NavigationFixer.StateChanged(InternalEntityEntry entry, EntityState oldState, Boolean fromQuery)
   at Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.ChangeTracking.Internal.InternalEntityEntryNotifier.StateChanged(InternalEntityEntry entry, EntityState oldState, Boolean fromQuery)  
   at Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.ChangeTracking.Internal.InternalEntityEntry.FireStateChanged(EntityState oldState)
   at Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.ChangeTracking.Internal.InternalEntityEntry.SetEntityState(EntityState oldState, EntityState newState, Boolean acceptChanges, Boolean 
modifyProperties)
   at Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.ChangeTracking.Internal.InternalEntityEntry.SetEntityState(EntityState entityState, Boolean acceptChanges, Boolean modifyProperties, Nullable`1 forceStateWhenUnknownKey)
   at Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.ChangeTracking.Internal.EntityGraphAttacher.PaintAction(EntityEntryGraphNode`1 node)
   at Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.ChangeTracking.Internal.EntityEntryGraphIterator.TraverseGraph[TState](EntityEntryGraphNode`1 node, Func`2 handleNode)
   at Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.ChangeTracking.Internal.EntityEntryGraphIterator.TraverseGraph[TState](EntityEntryGraphNode`1 node, Func`2 handleNode)
   at Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.ChangeTracking.Internal.EntityGraphAttacher.AttachGraph(InternalEntityEntry rootEntry, EntityState targetState, EntityState storeGeneratedWithKeySetTargetState, Boolean forceStateWhenUnknownKey)
   at Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Internal.InternalDbSet`1.SetEntityState(InternalEntityEntry entry, EntityState entityState)
   at Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Internal.InternalDbSet`1.Update(TEntity entity)
```

My entity looks like that:

```
public partial class Absence : IValidatableObject
    {
        public Absence()
        {
            AbsenceComments = new HashSet<AbsenceComment>();
        }
        [Key]
        public int AbsenceId { get; set; }
        public int? AbsenceStatusId { get; set; }
        [DateTimeValidator]
        public DateTime CreateDate { get; set; }
        [DateTimeValidator]
        public DateTime LastModifiedDate { get; set; }
        public DateTime? AbsenceFrom { get; set; }
        public DateTime? AbsenceUntil { get; set; }
        public int? AbsenceTypeId { get; set; }
        public int? AbsenceDetailTypeId { get; set; }
        public int? CostCenterId { get; set; }
        public string Adlogin { get; set; }
        public int Personalnummer { get; set; }

        public virtual AbsenceDetailType? AbsenceDetailType { get; set; }
        public virtual AbsenceStatus? AbsenceStatus { get; set; }
        public virtual AbsenceType? AbsenceType { get; set; }
        public virtual CostCenter? CostCenter { get; set; }
        public virtual PresenceListRawData? PersonalnummerNavigation { get; set; }
        public virtual ICollection<AbsenceComment>? AbsenceComments { get; set; }

        public IEnumerable<ValidationResult> Validate(ValidationContext validationContext)
        {
            Absence absenceToCheck = (Absence)validationContext.ObjectInstance;
            if (absenceToCheck.AbsenceUntil > absenceToCheck.AbsenceFrom)
            {
                yield return new ValidationResult("The absence until date has to be greater than the absence from date");
            }
        }
    }
```

I also added this in the Context class.

```
modelBuilder.Entity<Absence>(entity =>
            {
                entity.ToTable("Absence", "pre");
                entity.HasKey(c => c.AbsenceId);

                entity.Property(e => e.AbsenceFrom).HasColumnType("datetime");

                entity.Property(e => e.AbsenceUntil).HasColumnType("datetime");

                entity.Property(e => e.Adlogin)
                    .HasMaxLength(255)
                    .HasColumnName("ADLogin");

                entity.Property(e => e.CreateDate).HasColumnType("datetime");

                entity.Property(e => e.LastModifiedDate).HasColumnType("datetime");

                entity.HasOne(d => d.AbsenceDetailType)
                    .WithMany(p => p.Absences)
                    .HasForeignKey(d => d.AbsenceDetailTypeId)
                    .HasConstraintName("FK__Absence__Absence__6CA64BFC");

                entity.HasOne(d => d.AbsenceStatus)
                    .WithMany(p => p.Absences)
                    .HasForeignKey(d => d.AbsenceStatusId)
                    .HasConstraintName("FK__Absence__Absence__66ED72A6");

                entity.HasOne(d => d.AbsenceType)
                    .WithMany(p => p.Absences)
                    .HasForeignKey(d => d.AbsenceTypeId)
                    .HasConstraintName("FK__Absence__Absence__67E196DF");

                entity.HasOne(d => d.CostCenter)
                    .WithMany(p => p.Absences)
                    .HasForeignKey(d => d.CostCenterId)
                    .HasConstraintName("FK__Absence__CostCen__68D5BB18");

                entity.HasOne(d => d.PersonalnummerNavigation)
                    .WithMany(p => p.Absences)
                    .HasForeignKey(d => d.Personalnummer)
                    .OnDelete(DeleteBehavior.ClientSetNull)
                    .HasConstraintName("FK__Absence__Persona__6E8E946E");
            });
```

And here is the controller method, which should do the update call:

```
public IActionResult UpdateAbsences(int id, [FromBody] Absence absenceToUpdate)
        {
            if (this._context.Absences.Where(f => f.AbsenceId == id).Count() != 1)
            {
                return NotFound();
            }
            if (TryValidateModel(absenceToUpdate))
            {
                try
                {
                    this._context.Absences.Update(absenceToUpdate);
                }
                catch (Exception e)
                {
                    Console.WriteLine(e);
                }
                return Ok(true);
            }
            else
            {
                return BadRequest(ModelState);
            }
        }
```

I tried to add the `[Key]` attribute and I also tried to add `entity.HasKey(c => c.AbsenceId);`. But it doesn't seem to work. Do I have to send all the foreign key entries also. Can I not only update the foreign key id?

```
{
  "absenceId": 4,
  "absenceStatusId": 1,
  "createDate": "2022-10-19T00:00:00",
  "lastModifiedDate": "2022-10-19T00:00:00",
  "absenceFrom": "2022-10-19T00:00:00",
  "absenceUntil": null,
  "absenceTypeId": 1,
  "absenceDetailTypeId": 1,
  "costCenterId": 1,
  "adlogin": "test\\hans",
  "personalnummer": 200,
  "absenceDetailType": {
    "absenceDetailTypeId": 1,
    "typeName": "Ferien 1 Tag",
    "comments": null,
    "isDeleted": false,
    "absenceTypeId": 1,
    "absenceType": {
      "absenceTypeId": 1,
      "typeName": "Ferien",
      "comments": null,
      "isDeleted": false,
      "absenceDetailTypes": [
        null
      ],
      "absences": [
        null
      ]
    },
    "absences": [
      null
    ]
  },
  "absenceStatus": {
    "absenceStatusId": 1,
    "statusName": "Abgeschlossen",
    "comments": null,
    "isDeleted": false,
    "absences": [
      null
    ]
  },
  "absenceType": {
    "absenceTypeId": 1,
    "typeName": "Ferien",
    "comments": null,
    "isDeleted": false,
    "absenceDetailTypes": [
      {
        "absenceDetailTypeId": 1,
        "typeName": "Ferien 1 Tag",
        "comments": null,
        "isDeleted": false,
        "absenceTypeId": 1,
        "absenceType": null,
        "absences": [
          null
        ]
      }
    ],
    "absences": [
      null
    ]
  },
  "costCenter": {
    "costCenterId": 1,
    "costCenterName": "HR",
    "comments": "Test",
    "absences": [
      null
    ]
  },
  "personalnummerNavigation": null,
  "absenceComments": [],
  "absenceFromDate": "2022-10-19T22:00:00.000Z",
  "absenceUntilDate": null
}
```

Comment: Sound like a bug in EF Core.

Comment: Can show the content json of `absenceToUpdate`?

Comment: I added the JSON Request.

Answer (score 0):

This may be an issue with attempting to perform the `Update` with the data available. One slight warning sign is passing both an Id and then also having the Id within the model. If these don't match one could say "a record was found" while the data inside the model being updated is different. (Not likely, but it remains a possibility for problems) The other issue is passing/dealing with related data. The reference to "key" may not be referring to the Absence but references to the AbsenceDetailType or AbscenceStatus. That the JSON seems to show that there are bi-directional references back to Absences is another warning. Many-to-One relationships like this rarely need bi-directional references so I would recommend removing these where they are not absolutely necessary.

My advice in web applications is to *avoid* passing entities between view and server. It might appear that you are passing an entity, but what is coming back is serialized form data which is not the complete entity you had provided to the View. Using methods like `Update` and treating it like a detached entity is dangerous (from tampering), and prone to errors since the FormData will not be guaranteed to provide a complete picture of the entity.

Ideally you should use a purpose-built view model to represent the data to make up an updated vs. inserted entity, but using what you have:

```
if (!TryValidateModel(absenceToUpdate) 
   return BadRequest(ModelState);

var existingAbsence = _context.Absences.Single(f => f.AbsenceId == absenceToUpdate.AbsenceId); 

existingAbscence.AbsenceTypeId = absenceToUpdate.AbsenceTypeId;
// Copy across values that can change.

_context.SaveChanges();

return Ok(true);
```

When copying data between the provided values to update and the live "data" you can utilize something like Automapper to set up rules about what values can be copied across, then just use `Mapper.Map(absenceToUpdate, existingAbsence);` rather than copying values across one by one.

If you need to update reference data (references to other related entities) then it involves a little more work. In these cases check to see if a reference (FK) has changed and if so, load that new reference from the DbContext and update against the entity. The (fake) entity passed in is not a tracked entity for the DbContext, so using that can end up resulting in the DbContext treating it as a new record, leading to errors or duplication.

For example, if we want to update AbsenceStatus, if we just want to update the DB we can get away with just loading the Absence to update without eager loading related data, updating the FK and saving. (as was done above.) However, If we want to pass that Absence and it's status back to a view to refresh or otherwise ensure the AbsenceStatus navigation property is correct after making our change, we need to first ensure the references are eager loaded:

```
var existingAbsence = _context.Absences
    .Include(f => f.AbsenceStatus)
    .Single(f => f.AbsenceId == absenceToUpdate.AbsenceId);
```

Then detect whether the status needs to change and update the navigation property:

```
if (absenceToUpdate.AbsenceStatusId != existingAbsence.AbsenceStatusId)
{
    var status = _context.AbsenceStatuses.Single(x => x.AbsenceStatusId == absenceToUpdate.AbsenceStatusId);
    existingAbsence.AbsenceStatus = status;
}
```

Repeat for *every* reference that can be allowed to be changed.

Ideally the data should include something like a RowVersion number/timestamp that can be compared to detect cases where the data in the database may have been changed since the copy was taken to send to the view. (and was the basis for these changes)

For example:

```
var existingAbsence = _context.Absences.Single(f => f.AbsenceId == absenceToUpdate.AbsenceId); 
if(existingAbsence.RowVersionNumber != absenceToUpdate.RowVersionNumber)
{
    // Someone else has updated this row since this user fetched it. 
    // How do you want to handle this? Log and overwrite, or reject 
    // and inform the user to refresh their view and reapply their changes?
}
```

The next thing would be to employ a global exception handling policy and be explicit about what is considered a recoverable error (sent back to the client to retry) vs. a serious error which should be logged and terminate the client session, possibly locking their account for a period of time. If something comes across that isn't right, it could be a tamper attempt or there may be issues with the client session.